# Vauge PayFlow Error

Tags: paypal, error-handling, payflowpro

I'm using PayFlow with Layout C, which uses an iFrame to embed the payment form. I've followed the instructions found here for testing: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/

My request for a secure token returns successfully, but when I run a test charge, I get the following error:

> Some required information is missing or incorrect. Please correct the
>   fields below and try again.
>
> Error: An error has occurred. Please contact the system administrator.

The only fields below are card number and expiration date, which follow the testing guidelines.

What else could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the secure token, Instead of using the redirection url "https://payflowlink.paypal.com" , you should use "https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com" if you are in test mode .

This change happened after a certificate upgrade on 8th APR . You can check the link below :

https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1236

Comment: Using "https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com" as the src of my iframe returns a connection error.

Comment: Is there any website I can check on your integration ?