# Getting Failed to connect to host Input Server Uri = https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com:443

Tags: paypal

Getting this response for a very basic paypal payments advanced call:

Transaction failed! Please try again with another payment method.
(server response follows)

```
Array
(
    [STATE] => CA
    [RESPMSG] => Failed to connect to host Input Server Uri = https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com:443
    [SHIPTOSTREET] => 1234 Park Ave
    [SHIPTOSTATE] => CA
    [STREET] => 123 Main St.
    [SHIPTOCITY] => San Jose
    [LASTNAME] => Doe
    [FIRSTNAME] => John
    [SHIPTOZIP] => 95101
    [SECURETOKEN] => 8dov2tKpHS02bZjINimuKFAEV
    [AMT] => 1.00
    [SHIPTOLASTNAME] => Smith
    [SECURETOKENID] => MySecTokenID-5547c1b32dc2b
    [CITY] => San Jose
    [SHIPTOFIRSTNAME] => Jane
    [ZIP] => 95101
    [RESULT] => -1
    [TRXTYPE] => A
)
```

I'm using php code samples that I obtained from a paypal docs page (actually it linked to a github repo), though I can't seem to find it again among the absurdly convoluted wilderness of extraneous docs that paypal has you trudge through to accomplish the simplest of tasks.

Its a basic iframe demo, layout c. The service is a debian linux distro

Update: Here is a link to the original doc reference that I used to get up and going: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929

Note that I'm using the "try the demos" zip (php) found in section 6. The demo and the docs there show the iframe as not having the pilot url, which by a suggestion here in the comments says it should be.

In updating the iframe url to the pilot url, I now get a new timeout error:

```
Array
(
    [STATE] => CA
    [TYPE] => A
    [ACCT] => 1111
    [ZIPTOSHIP] => 95101
    [BILLTOLASTNAME] => Doe
    [BILLTONAME] => John Doe
    [SHIPTOCITY] => San Jose
    [LASTNAME] => Doe
    [PNREF] => B10P7E8A02A7
    [TENDER] => CC
    [METHOD] => CC
    [SHIPTOZIP] => 95101
    [ADDRESSTOSHIP] => 1234 Park Ave
    [BILLTOFIRSTNAME] => John
    [AMT] => 1.00
    [SHIPTOCOUNTRY] => US
    [TRANSTIME] => 2015-05-05 10:40:36
    [NAMETOSHIP] => Jane Smith
    [ZIP] => 95101
    [BILLTOCOUNTRY] => US
    [EXPDATE] => 1215
    [STATETOSHIP] => CA
    [RESPMSG] => Timeout waiting for Processor response
    [COUNTRY] => US
    [SHIPTOSTATE] => CA
    [BILLTOZIP] => 95101
    [SHIPTOSTREET] => 1234 Park Ave
    [BILLTOCITY] => San Jose
    [TAX] => 0.00
    [BILLTOSTATE] => CA
    [CARDTYPE] => 0
    [FIRSTNAME] => John
    [AVSDATA] => XXN
    [CITYTOSHIP] => San Jose
    [SECURETOKEN] => 88saMEY6aCkyh09bhzHgE1w1i
    [SECURETOKENID] => MySecTokenID-5549007e7d1fe
    [CITY] => San Jose
    [NAME] => John Doe
    [COUNTRYTOSHIP] => US
    [BILLTOSTREET] => 123 Main St.
    [RESULT] => 104
    [TRXTYPE] => A
    [ADDRESS] => 123 Main St.
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765339/vauge-payflow-error/29769900?noredirect=1#comment47690273_29769900

Comment: It suggests I use https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com, which I am. That is crux of the error.

Comment: Whenever you use PayPal advanced Integration , you use two endpoints , first to create the secure token ( https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com") and the second to open the Iframe ( https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com"). So I am talking about the second endpoint .

Comment: So I updated the iframe url to be the pilot url as well (saw no where in the docs  that said I should do that of course). However now I getting a timeout failure..  [RESPMSG] => Timeout waiting for Processor response

Comment: If you have used the card "411111111111111" , kindly try to use this one "4446283288706522"

Comment: Eshan That worked! Could  you please supply that as answer for so I can confirm it for others who may run into the same issue? So have they changed the dummy cc number and forgotten to update the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are in test environment you need to make sure you are using the endpoint "https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com" once you created the secure token.

Apart from that if you are getting "the time out waiting for host error" while using the card "4111111111111111" trying using the any card from before link and it should work fine.

http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/

Comment: To be clear the endpoint "https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com" must also be used for the iframe source.